# Passing variable name as command line argument to print

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I was wondering if this is possible

```
a = 100
b = 200
c = 300

print(argv[1])
```

I want to print value of *a* when `argv[1] = a`, i.e. when I run program from command line as

```
python test.py a
```

Output should be `100`.

And same for other the variables `b` and `c`. Is it something possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I'm not sure you should, but you can, this way:

```
import sys

a = 100
b = 200
c = 300

print(globals()[sys.argv[1]])
```

Comment: BTW, I see many others gave answers about retrieving the values from a dictionary, rather than from global variables. Although those answers do not do what OP requested, I do believe they are better practice. I would not really do `globals()[sys.argv[1]]` in my own code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries to achieve this:

```
to_print = {
  "a": 100,
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300
}

print(to_print.get(argv[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict`:

```
d = {"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": 300}

print(d.get(argv[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
values = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300}
print(values[argv[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
import sys
values = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print(values[sys.argv[1]])
    except KeyError:
        print("Provide correct arguments")
```